# ASP.NET MVC localization best practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I need help with the best practice to localize asp mvc apps,
I saw Oxite having a base method named Localize in the BaseController, but is the Localization a task for the view or the Controller?
Or should I use resx files / or use db tables?

Comment: this is a nice approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381070/asp-net-mvc-localization-best-practice/12936708#12936708

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create your own Html helper and use it like `<%= Html.Resource("Name") %>`

Details are in [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20081222191210/http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx) post.

Comment: Just so everyone is aware, the post Ihar links to now has an update.  See: http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/10/ASPNET-MVC-Simplified-Localization-via-ViewEngines.aspx

Comment: Am already using a solution similar to this, but isn't this type of solution adding an extra overhead in terms of performance?

Answer (score 10):

There is good solution for this available [here](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html)

this article covers all aspects of localization asp.net mvc app

Answer (score 4):

Since this a one year question and I don't know the scope of my answer over here. Recently I faced a situation like this , ie I need to implement the localization for different languages in my mvc site.

I considered using `Resource` file.
 its very easy to implement, but the issue is that during the phase of development, we need to specify the localized strings. So if it a multi language support, we need to make the resource file for every language. If client what to change or add a new language, its very difficult and we need to provide a build.

Second I consider the `Satelite Assemblies`.
 Its also similar to Resource, but it gives a freedom to edit the assemblies out side and put it back to bin folder. This also requires a lot of effort to client/developer.

Third I considered storing in db.
 This approach is fine and we have some mechanism to read data from the server. This requires one time effort and client doesn't have any dependable .

I override a custom `DisplayNameAttributre` and from the constructor I will pass DB and get the data to render

Based on your requirement it should display the view to you.

**Resource Manager**

```
/// <summary>
    ///  Extended display attribute which will handles the request
    ///  It will call every time when the property is rendered (return View() - from controller)
    /// </summary>
    public class ResourceManagerAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
    {
        public ResourceManagerAttribute(string resourceKey, string resourceNameSpace = "")
            : base(GetDisplayName(resourceKey, resourceNameSpace))
        { }

        private static string GetDisplayName(string resourceKey, string resourceNameSpace = "")
        {
            // get the browser's prefered language.

            string browserLanguage = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages.First();

            // Get the locale data for that property and displays.
            switch (browserLanguage)
            {
                case "en-US": return "Eng " + resourceKey;
             // calls db based on resource key
                case "hi": return "Hin " + resourceKey;

            }
            return "-- Not Implemented Now -- ";
        }
```

---

**ViewModel**

```
public class HomeViewModel
    {
        //calls the resource
        [ResourceManager("MID")]
        public int MID { get; set; }
        [ResourceManager("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ResourceManager("Addess")]
        public string Addess { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

MVC is really more about using the right view for the right job. Putting everything in a resource file is extremely paintfull. It's good to use resource files for small things, but for larger pages like your description pages, its better to have a view in each culture with a lot of content. For example using the following structure:
~/Views/en-US/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/pt-BR/Home/Index.aspx
or this structure:
~/Views/Home/Index.en-US.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.en-US.aspx

read the blog for how to do it: http://blog.oimae.com/2011/02/20/cultured-view-engine-for-mvc/

Comment: Why the -1 on this answer?  There are [several](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) [reputable](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) [examples](http://brianreiter.org/2011/03/23/simple-asp-net-mvc-globalization-with-graceful-fallback/) of this pattern and when it's indicated.  The answerer here has a point: managing large text content in a .resx adds some friction, and may have layout or sizing impact on a largely textual view.  This is a fundamental tradeoff, as illustrated in the links.

Comment: By FAR the worst solution - ever! If you need to scale across lot of languages and locales, this becomes a pretty big mess and is super painfull to maintenance. Better approach is to put all stuff in a localization DB, load the required content on app start (dont forget an update-cache-button on some page) + use some type of browser-interface/frontend to edit the strings. Also, this system scales well across a team of translators and "content-maintainers" (in your soution instead, they would need to be aware of HTML/CSS/JS, at least to a level at which they do not destroy stuff in the views).

Answer (score 0):

If the string to be localized is generated by the view (eg a label in front of a text field), then its localization should be in the View.

If the string is generated by the Controller, its localization should be there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would better go for creating a custom MetadataProvider and using a convention for the models. Something like 1 resource file by model namespace and a convention like ModelName.PropertyName -> value

For validators, common buttons and so a resource file.

For views text i am actually trying to find a good way. Maybe a view pre-process before compilation and a custom Scope for localized texts, so the pre-process can create the resource file for each view with the default language.